# Using graphQL and sequelize find value of previous entries in sorted query relative to parent query

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

Edit:
I have an order with has many items.
The items have one order.

The goal is to have a query that returns previous values for a column of the item as an array with the length of a supplied argument.

So if I have:

```
{
 orders: [
    {
      orderDate: 1,
      items: [
        {
          itemName: 'Item 1',
          orderAmount: 2,
          itemId: '1a'
        },
        {
          itemName: 'Item 2',
          orderAmount: 7,
          itemId: '1b'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      orderDate: '2',
      items: [
        {
          itemName: 'Item 1',
          orderAmount: 3,
          itemId: '1a'
        },
        {
          itemName: 'Item 2',
          orderAmount: 6,
          itemId: '1b'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      orderDate: '3',
      items: [
        {
          itemName: 'Item 1',
          orderAmount: 4,
          itemId: '1a'
        },
        {
          itemName: 'Item 2',
          orderAmount: 5,
          itemId: '1b'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like is a query that includes returning previousOrders(count:2) to return...

```
  orderDate: 3,
  items: [
    {
      itemName: 'Item 1',
      orderAmount: 4,
      itemId: '1a'
      previousOrders: [3, 2]
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Item 2',
      orderAmount: 5,
      itemId: '1a'
      previousOrders: [6, 7]
    }
```

What I currently have working is...

```
previousOrders: async (item, { count }, { models }) => {
  const previous = await models.Item.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'orderAmount'],
    where: {
      itemId: item.itemId
    },
    include: [
      {
        attributes: [],
        model: models.Order
      }
    ],
    order: [[models.Order, 'orderDate', 'desc']],
    raw: true
  })
  const index = previous.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id)
  const sliced = previous.slice(index + 1, index + count + 1)
  const array = sliced.map(a => a.orderAmount)
  while (array.length < count) {
    array.push(0)
  }
  return array
```

This works but I feel like there is probably a much nicer way to do it with queries and just want to see other potentials.

Comment: We're lacking a lot of context here. At the very least, you should show how Order and Item are associated. I'm guessing an order has multiple items, but an item has only one order? And if I'm understanding your question, given a particular order, your intent is to fetch all items associated with the two orders preceding the order in question?

Comment: Thank you.  I hopefully clarified a bit and added some context.  Sorry for the poor quality of my original question.